# Calling a method without brackets for Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I wish to extend the `String` class and add a simple method:

```
String.prototype.world = function(){
  return " world";
}
```

and I want to do something like:

```
"hello".world
```

and get back `"hello world"`. instead of doing:

```
"hello".world()
```

calling a function without brackets will return the function object.

What I'm looking for is to execute the function instead of returning it (without specifying the brackets).

Can I do it somehow in JavaScript?

**EDIT**: according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter), using `__defineGetter__` is non standard and deprecated. looking for alternativs.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Im pretty sure the answer is no; See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752800/dynamic-property-of-javascript-object

Comment: @GustavCarlson so later i can have something like: 3.days.ago

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using setter getter. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nYBRY/). but setter getter are not supported by IE < 9;

```
 function getter(){
    return this + " world";
  }
  if(Object.__defineGetter__){ // chrome 
  String.prototype.__defineGetter__('world', getter);
}else{
 Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'world', { // IE
                    get : getter
                });
}
```

Comment: according to this article it's deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter

Comment: @sagivo There are two way to define properties see the solution . Object.defineProperty is supported by FF. Object.defineProperty in console. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Answer (score 3):

You can define a getter like this:

```
String.prototype.__defineGetter__("world", function() {
    return this + ' world';
});

'hello'.world // 'hello world'
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qEKFP/)

Comment: according to this article it's deprecated: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter